# Does Spring Container call the bean's constructor? If not, how to initialize fields to new instances using the "new" keyword?

Tags: java, spring

I have a class like this -

```
class Messages
  {
      ...
      LinkedList<String> inputs;
      LinkedList<String> outputs;
      ...
  }
```

Normally, I would initialize inputs and outputs in the constructor -

```
public Messages()
 {
    inputs = new LinkedList<String>();
    outputs = new LinkedList<String>();
 }
```

However, I want to achieve the same result using spring configuration. So what should I put under the following node?

```
<bean id="Messages" class="com.somename.Messages">
                                                   <--- what goes here?
</bean>
```

When the Spring Container creates the "Messages" bean, will it call the constructor also?

Comment: Seems like just trying it would have answered that? Plus it's tough to create an object without calling a constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will call the constructor. It would be very odd for an IoC container *not* to call a constructor - it would have to go to some lengths to construct an instance of the object without going through a constructor, and it would almost always be a bad idea.

Of course, you can also initialize your variables as part of the declaration:

```
class Messages
{
    ...
    private final LinkedList<String> inputs = new LinkedList<String>();
    private final LinkedList<String> outputs = new LinkedList<String>();
    ...
}
```

Comment: @jon: I think OP want to initialize values in spring configuration file rather than in old java fashion.  (I might/must be wrong as I am skeptical about THE JON SKEETS answer)

Comment: @Ajinkya: I don't see any evidence of that. All I see is the OP asking whether Spring will call a constructor.

Comment: @JonSkeet: OP mentioned `However, I want to achieve the same result using spring configuration. So what should I put under the following node? ` and he have added a piece of bean configuration file asking what he should add there.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's worth mentioning that behaviour for proxied objects can be quite tricky.

Spring is quite complex when it comes to creating proxies. For example, as of Spring 3.2, CGLIB is re-packaged under `org.springframework` and it will call a constructor at least once to create a proxy.

It can be [more than once](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/aop/73853-cglib-proxy-method-calls-constructor-twice) it seems when we talk about AOP.

At the same time, as of Spring 4.0, the constructor of your proxied object will NOT be called twice anymore since the CGLIB proxy instance will be created via Objenesis.

Objenesis is a small lib used to instantiate an object without calling the constructor.

So, there's not simple yes or no answer. Surely, constructor will be called at some point to instantiate an object regardless of the framework. But in the modern frameworks there are some tricks that help to reduce the amount of constructor calls to a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Spring will call the constructor. It will also match constructor arguments if there are any.

Here it is explained in detail http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-collaborators

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to initialize without any data than you can do that in constructor as for object creation contrstuctor will be called. If you want to assign the specific data, than you should have setters in your class and need to use them while creating the bean.

Comment: Or you can initialize via a ctor with parameters.